# Custom email subject and body in riemann

Tags: clojure, riemann

I am using email alert in riemann. I have hardecoded the value for `:subject` and `:body'. I am facing some issue in this. I pasted my riemann code and the error I got below. I don't know how to resolve this.

```
(let [email (mailer {:host "smtp.gmail.com"
                            :port 25
                            :user "user"
                            :pass "password"
                            :auth "true"
                            :subject "Welcome All to Coding"
                            :body "Hello Team, \n Welcome to my coding \n Thank You!"
                            :from "mygmail@gmail.com"})])
```

I got the below error

```
WARN [2015-07-25 02:10:17,640] defaultEventExecutorGroup-2-2 - riemann.config -
riemann.email$mailer$make_stream__7892$stream__7893@62aa5 threw
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IF
n
        at riemann.email$email_event.invoke(email.clj:15)
        at riemann.email$mailer$make_stream__7892$stream__7893.invoke(email.clj:
69)
        at riemann.config$eval96$stream__101$fn__106.invoke(riemann_v1.con
fig:39)
        at riemann.config$eval96$stream__101.invoke(riemann_v1.config:39)
        at riemann.streams$smap$stream__3695$fn__3706.invoke(streams.clj:163)
        at riemann.streams$smap$stream__3695.invoke(streams.clj:163)
        at riemann.streams$fixed_time_window_fn$stream__3946$fn__3979.invoke(str
eams.clj:381)
        at riemann.streams$fixed_time_window_fn$stream__3946.invoke(streams.clj:
381)
        at riemann.config$eval96$stream__145$fn__150.invoke(riemann_v1.con
fig:27)
        at riemann.config$eval96$stream__145.invoke(riemann_v1.config:27)
        at riemann.core$stream_BANG_$fn__5678.invoke(core.clj:19)
        at riemann.core$stream_BANG_.invoke(core.clj:18)
        at riemann.transport$handle.invoke(transport.clj:159)
        at riemann.transport.tcp$tcp_handler.invoke(tcp.clj:93)
        at riemann.transport.tcp$gen_tcp_handler$fn__5904.invoke(tcp.clj:65)
        at riemann.transport.tcp.proxy$io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAda
pter$ff19274a.channelRead(Unknown Source)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(Abst
ractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$700(AbstractCha
nnelHandlerContext.java:32)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$8.run(AbstractChannelH
andlerContext.java:324)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor.run(DefaultEventExecuto
r.java:36)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThread
EventExecutor.java:116)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorato
r.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I commented the `:subject` and `:body`. I am not getting the error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide functions for subject and body instead of just strings. From [the docs](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.email.html#var-mailer)

> By default, riemann uses `(subject events)` and `(body events)` to format emails.
>   You can set your own subject or body formatter functions by including
>   `:subject` or `:body` in msg-opts. These formatting functions take a sequence of
>   events and return a string.
>
> ```
> (def email (mailer {} {:body (fn [events] 
>                                (apply prn-str events))}))
> ```

So to just have a constant string you could use:

```
(fn [events] "Your Subject Text")
```

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation was very clear to understand and its working